# SQL Server Raiserror not causing exception in .NET client

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure on a SQL Server 2005 database which has a statement like this:

```
  IF @Condition = 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('some error message',16,1)
        RETURN
    END
```

and it's called from a C# client like so:

```
 try
           {
                SomeVariable = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(GetConnectionString(), "MySP", new object[] { param1, param2});
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

However there's no exception being raised. The condition in the SP is always true for testing. To verify this, I copied the call from SQL Server Profiler and executed it in a query window and the ErrorMessage was printed which means the error is raised.

Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your catch statement, to see if it's even getting executed at all?

Comment: Yes. That's how I found out it's not working.

Comment: May be the following comment can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141845/throw-vs-raiserror/24285511#comment110362356_24285511

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through the SQL Helper class and found out that ExecuteScalar eats the exception and returns null. I switched to ExecuteDataSet which doesn't do this. I expected the different Execute.. method to behave the same way. The other way is to use ExecuteScalar and when the SP detects an error, it does a SELECT some error number which can be handled in the client.

Comment: Thanks for writing this 14 years ago.  We have been struggling for 2 days trying to diagnose an issue, this helped us answer the question in only a few minutes!

Answer (score 2):

According to SQL Books online severity of 16 "Indicates general errors that can be corrected by the user." - so that severity is OK.

I only have SQL 2008 to work with, but I  have tested the RAISERROR('some error message',16,1) and the error was caught in my c# app. Are you sure the error is not being handled in your "SqlHelper" class?

Comment: Thanks. I read your comment after I did my analysis which had the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

From the Books online

Specify a severity of 10 or lower to use RAISERROR to return a message from a TRY block *without* invoking the CATCH block.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something to do with the severity level?  If you up severity to 19 does it raise the exception through to your code?

Comment: severity levels above 11 is an error which can be handled by the client.