# Inserting value into database

Tags: c#, sql

I wanted to insert values into database but it is not working eventhough my code perfectly working when its used as stored procedure. I am trieng to use button click to store the value. Please tell whats wrong with the code. Its not showing any error or exception but data is not getting updated in the table

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sales(acnum, scripname, shares_bought) VALUES ('12', 'abcd', '20')";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();                                
}
```

Comment: what is your exeption?

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You get any exception or error message? Is it works on database manager? What are the types of your columns? I strongly suspect you should not store your `12` and `20` as a character. Can you please be more specific? And `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text` is redundant. It is `.Text` by default.

Comment: no exception .. . no errors but its not updating in database

Comment: my columns acnum and shares_bought are "int" and scripname is "varchar"

Comment: Can you please paste your error or exception?

Comment: INSERT INTO sales(acnum, scripname, shares_bought) VALUES (12, 'abcd', 20)

Comment: @AwnAli: may depend on the database - MySQL will automatically convert strings to integers where necessary.

Comment: @AwnAli no errors and exception Ali.. database doesnot get updated

Comment: Strongly suggest looking at `Dapper`. Might make a lot of these complexities disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my columns acnum and shares_bought are "int" and scripname is
>   "varchar"

Then you will not need single quotes for your integer values. Use it as;

```
...VALUES (12, 'abcd', 20)"
```

A few things more;

- Use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.
- You don't need `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text` line. It is `.Text` *by default*.

---

```
var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
using(var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(conStr))
using(var cmd = sqlConnection1.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sales(acnum, scripname, shares_bought) VALUES (12, 'abcd', 20)";
   sqlConnection1.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: tried tht also sir, but still not working and removed command type line still its not working

Comment: @Darkknight _not working_ is not useful at all. What do you mean by that. You will get any error or something? Is this query works on your sql server?

Comment: yes sir this query works in sql server but its not working in my visual studio... it does not show any errors or exceptions

Comment: This can be database dependant - MySQL does automatic type conversion so both 12 and '12' are acceptable values for an integer column.

Comment: @PaulF I didn't know that but looks like OP using SQL Server.

Comment: @Darkknight Are you sure your connection string is right? Is your `sales` table belongs on default schema? Maybe you need to write `dbo.sales` or something?

Comment: @SonerGönül I'm sure this connection string is right and dbo.sales is not necessary I think because without "dbo." it has worked perfectly fine in previous webpage where I had to take values from textbox.

Comment: @SonerGönül Do u have any idea where it can go wrong??

Comment: @Darkknight I honestly don't know, This should work. What is the size of your `varchar` column?

Comment: Have you checked the return value of ExecuteNonQuery - that will show how many rows were updated.

Comment: @Darkknight By the way you said; _I had to take values from textbox._ But in your code, you don't. Are you sure this is _real_ code?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024109/how-can-i-get-an-error-message-that-happens-when-using-executenonquery

Comment: Can you try manually running the query - for example from a  command line utility like sqlcmd or workbench like MySQL Workbench - these may give better error reporting to see what the issue is. Maybe spelling mistake of field name, or entering a duplicate not allowed by a unique index for example.

Comment: @PaulF I have tried to run the query in sql, it had run perfectly... it did updated the database, but while i try to use the same query in visual studio, it is producing no result.

Comment: @SonerGönül no I mean in my last webpage I had to take value from textbox which worked fine.. but in this page I had to add value which is not working.

Comment: See if you can use the InfoMessage event to get more info : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37102/Using-InfoMessage-Event-of-SqlConnection-Object

Answer (score 1):

Set breakpoint in code and see if code is executing. In case you don't know how to, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx).
As you are not getting any exception on insert statement and it's not reflecting in database, either you have different connection string or your code is not getting executed.