# Exception is not raised

Tags: c#, sql-server, raiseerror

I have a stored procedure that contains the following code:

```
IF @somevar IS NULL
BEGIN
RAISERROR (N'Station %d does not exist.', -- Message text.
       10, -- Severity,
       7, -- State,
       @id); 
END
```

I want to catch the SqlException in C# code. But that exception is not raised. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a higher severity level; try it with a severity of at least 11. Also, are you using ExecuteScalar - which seems to eat exceptions? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010383/sql-server-raiserror-not-causing-exception-in-net-client).

Answer (score 3):

I'd try looking at the severity you're using.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this: - I use 16 all the time

```
 RAISERROR ('Message here', 16, 1)
```

[**[Details here]**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx)

> **0-9** Informational messages that return status information or report
>   errors that are not severe. The Database Engine does not raise system
>   errors with severities of 0 through 9.
>
> **10** Informational messages that return status information or report
>   errors that are not severe. For compatibility reasons, the Database
>   Engine converts severity 10 to severity 0 before returning the error
>   information to the calling application.
>
> **11-16** Indicate errors that can be corrected by the user.
>
> **20-24** Indicate system problems and are fatal errors, which means that
>   the Database Engine task that is executing a statement or batch is no
>   longer running. The task records information about what occurred and
>   then terminates. In most cases, the application connection to the
>   instance of the Database Engine may also terminate. If this happens,
>   depending on the problem, the application might not be able to
>   reconnect. Error messages in this range can affect all of the
>   processes accessing data in the same database and may indicate that a
>   database or object is damaged. Error messages with a severity level
>   from 19 through 24 are written to the error log.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `THROW instruction`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee677615.aspx