# THROW vs. RAISERROR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
THROW 51051, 'I come from the THROW construct :)', 1 ;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Could not find stored procedure 'THROW'.
```

Isn't the `THROW` procedure a sytem procedure? Why can't it find it?

Furthhermore, what is the difference between unsing `THROW` and `ErrorState` ? Is one older/newer/better than the other?
And what do "ErrorSeverity" and "ErrorState" mean by `ErrorState`? Can I define them as I will or they are predefined?

Comment: Which version are you using? You have tagged both 2008 and 2012.

Comment: @Rahul: We are using 2008 R2

Comment: That's why you are getting that error cause `THROW` is available from SQL2012 onwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is, but [only since 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). If you're using 2008R2, then it didn't exist.

The definitions of state and severity are clearly documented in the [raiserror](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) documentation

Answer (score 31):

According to the [Differences Between `RAISERROR` and `THROW` in **Sql Server**](http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/):

> Both `RAISERROR` and `THROW` statements are used to raise an error in **Sql Server**.
>
> The journey of `RAISERROR` started from **Sql Server 7.0**; whereas the journey of the `THROW` statement has just begun with **Sql Server 2012**.
>
> *Microsoft* is suggesting we start using the `THROW` statement instead of `RAISERROR`. The `THROW` statement seems to be simpler and easier to use than `RAISERROR`.

Comment: In fact - `RAISERROR can’t be used in the Sql Server 2014’s Natively compiled Stored Procedures`. So it all seemed to be moving in the direction of using more `THROW`

Comment: Everyone curious about this should read that link.  I think the difference between how the batch is treated is an especially important 'gotcha'.

Comment: I note that `RAISERROR( 'message text', 2, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT;` is still useful for outputing messages to the client without actually raising an error, so `RAISERROR` **can** be used for non-error conditions, whereas `THROW` cannot.

Comment: Yes, it’s very important to know that statements after RAISERROR **will still be executed**, whereas THROW terminates the batch.

Comment: @dakab if you use severity 20 statements will not be executed but only members of sysadmin role can execute it.